# How to make the bend of the letter 'Z' like in the Amazon logo?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

[image: Amazon logo]

If we observe the Amazon logo, the bend of the letter "Z" is perfectly aligned with the bend of the arrowhead. Is there any trick used in Adobe Illustrator to do it or will I have to manually experiment with the direct selection tool?

Answer (score 3):

- After typing the word > Menu **Type** > **Create Outlines**
- Draw a rounded corner rectangle with the same height and width as the lower stroke of the **Z**

[image: rectangle]

- Menu **Effect** > **Warp** > **Arch**

[image: ARCC]

- Menu **Object** > **Expand Appearance**

[image: expand]

- Select it together with the Z and using the **Shape Builder Tool** + <kbd>Alt</kbd> delete the leftover parts

[image: SHAPE BUILDER TOOL]

[image: buildertool]

Comment: as much as your answer tells how to make the arch in the z, it doesn't explain how to follow the exact curve of the arrow.

Comment: Is it that exact? https://ibb.co/dSRciT

Comment: Danielillo's answer seems to be the precise way of how this was accomplished. To clarify the 2nd part of your question: If you want the bottom part to be exact you could use a copy of the top part of the arrow to cut out the bottom part of the Z with Pathfinder/Minus Front. Let's say you want the bottom part of the Z to be the exact same shape than the arrow you could cut out that part of the arrow and use Pathfinder/Unite. But like I said it's not what was used here.

Comment: @BenoitLussier I thought about putting a similar explanation, but then I checked that at the original logo, the lower stroke of the Z doesn't have the same curvature as the arrow. Anyway, good appreciation.

Comment: If it *were* **perfectly** aligned, I'd say the simplest approach would be a rather deep stroke on a copy of the arrowhead, that stroke expanded, and then the resulting path used in the pathfinder palette as a subtraction, but I agree - on close examination, it's ***not*** a *perfect match*.